# Transferring array values that are strings to other HTML pages with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, html, post

the below is my PHP and HTML5 codes:

Inputs from a different page:

```
<p> Items: <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='produck[]' id='produck1' value='Item 1' /><label> Item 1 </label>
        <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='produck[]' id='produck2' value='Item 2' /><label> Item 2 </label>
        <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='produck[]' id='produck3' value='Item 3' /><label> Item 3 </label>
        <br />
</p>
```

Another page:

```
<?php
$product = $_POST['produck'];
?>

<table class='center' border='1'>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Value</th>
         <tr><td>Product</td><td><?php echo $product;?></td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm getting **Notice: Array to string conversion**. The values in `produck` is an array that consists of strings and upon looking up, it seems like I could use `print_r`. But when I do, I get the position of the string instead of the string itself.

What should I do to get the content of the string?

Comment: What string are you talking about? To output array values use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: By strings I meant the values in the first HTML section, like Item 1 and Item 2. I'm trying the foreach loop you provided below now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code to start with is:

```
<table class='center' border='1'>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Value</th>
<?php
foreach ($_POST['produck'] as $product) {?>
    <tr><td>Product</td><td><?php echo $product;?></td></tr>
<?php
}?>
</table>
```

So, as you can see, you should **iterate** over your array to output its' values.

Comment: I'm still getting the same notice but I understand what you're trying to say

Comment: So, what do you see when you `print_r($_POST['produck'])`?

Comment: I was getting the same error because I had issues with other pages but all and all, `foreach` was what I needed, thank you.